# Cropping transparency in an image

Tags: php, gd

I have a PNG image, which has a transparent background.

I'm using PHP GD to display these images, from a server. Is it possible in GD to also trim this transparent background, while maintaining the remainder of the image to be transparent and if so, how would I do it?

eg. original image: http://puu.sh/8pNdx/ab2ff1e64f.png

and the expected result after processing would be:
http://puu.sh/8pNg7/7b7ec85459.png

Answer (score 0):

If it is really important to remove transparent pixels than you will have to write a small custom algorithm.

1. First try to find none transparent boundary pixels. i.e. Pixels that actually define boundary of your object.
2. Than create a new transparent Bitmap according to position of those identified boundary pixels.
3. Than draw all your none transparent pixels on that new Bitmap according to new adjusted position.

Try searching for some efficient algorithm for:

> separating objects from an image

I hope it will help.

Comment: I don't want to remove all of the transparent pixels. I just want to, sort of, "trim" the image so that that giant uneven border is removed.

Comment: Each image irrespective of whatever shapes it has inside if of a Square/Rectangle dimensions. So I don’t mean that it will remove all transparent pixels. But it will help you removing 95% or more extra transparent pixels around your object. To me it’s like separating an object from a background. Background can be transparent or colour. It does not matter.
But still you will have to write some logic.